# LaTeX Template for Question and answer

Tags: exercises

I am looking for a LaTeX template (if anyone has created such a template) that will allow me to layout a question on the left side then and answer on the right side, followed by a brief annotation describing the question and answer in more detail.

I am inspired by the Socratic Method used in 'Little Schemer' by Daniel Friedman.

Does any know of a template that comes close?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A bit more detail as to exactly what you are looking for would be helpful, along with what you have tired so far and what you would like to improve.  Otherwise you can just put two `minipages` next to each other to obtain the question on the left and and the answer on the right hand side.

Comment: To follow up on @PeterGrill's questions: Should the two columns (left for questions, right for answers) be equally wide? If not, which fractions of the total width of the text block should each column occupy?

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, I will try using minipages as you mentioned.

Comment: @Mico I would like them to be equal, something like a html table with two td's in a row, and borders on top and bottom (and collapsed for subsequent rows - (re:html) it's the only way i can describe it without drawing it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of putting two `minipage`s next to each other: One for the question and one for the answer:

[image]

If you want the two `minipage`s aligned at the top use `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}% Question goes here
    \textbf{Question:}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus massa enim, suscipit vel lacinia elementum, tempus sed ipsum. Fusce turpis tortor, aliquet nec volutpat suscipit, dictum eu justo. Quisque viverra lacus at mi bibendum suscipit vulputate enim blandit. Proin in tempor ligula.
\end{minipage}
\hfill% Separate the Question and Answer
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}% Answer goes here
    \textbf{Answer:}
    Nam a nunc libero, eu varius neque. Curabitur elit velit, dictum sed dignissim in, blandit nec tortor. Sed at dolor pharetra urna eleifend luctus vitae et lorem. Aenean rhoncus molestie odio, sit amet molestie sapien varius et. 
\end{minipage}

\bigskip\noindent
\textbf{More details here:}
Nulla semper nisl vitae tellus placerat at egestas urna consectetur. Vivamus tempor augue arcu. Aenean non augue blandit erat molestie bibendum et sit amet enim. Vivamus mauris nunc, vestibulum non luctus in, feugiat id nunc. Aliquam ultricies magna eget odio bibendum vitae facilisis lacus mollis.
\end{document}
```